# best way to extract the first-name and last-name from sentence python (Persian text)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have over **20,000** first and last name and I want to check the sentence if in that sentence is any `first-name` or `last-name` of my `dataset`, this is my `dataset`

```
l-name   f-name  
میلاد  جورابلو
علی    احمدی
امیر    احمدی
```

this is the `sentence` sample

```
sentence = 'امروز با میلاد احمدی رفتم بیرون'
```

the english version the `dataset`

```
l-name    f-name
Smith     John
Johnson   Anthony
Williams  Ethan
```

this is the sentence in english version

```
sentence = 'I am going out with John Williams today'
```

I want my out put be like this

```
first_name = ['John']
last_name = ['Williams']
```

Comment: what if the sentence contains more than 1 first name or last name?

Comment: @TomerS It is better to make a list of them like this `first_name = ['John', 'Ethan']`

Comment: depends, my question is what if more than one name exists in a sentence? what will be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get lists of names from each column and check if a string contains any element from those lists.

```
import pandas as pd 

names = [['John', 'Smith'], ['Anthony', 'Johnson'], ['Ethan', 'Williams']]
df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns = ['f_name', 'l_name'])


fname_list = df['f_name'].to_list()
lname_list = df['l_name'].to_list()

sentence = 'I am going out with John Williams today'
sentence = sentence.split()

fname_exist = [e for e in sentence if(e in fname_list)]
lname_exist = [e for e in sentence if(e in lname_list)]

if(len(fname_exist) > 0 and len(lname_exist) > 0):
    print('first name: ' + fname_exist[0])
    print('last name name: ' + lname_exist[0])
```

Output:

```
first name: John
last name: Williams
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to approach this in a naive way you could consider regex, however this is based on the assumption that all first and last names are capitalised.

```
sentence = 'I am going out with John Williams today'
name = re.search(r"[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+ [A-Z]{1}[a-z]+", sentence).group()
print(name) # Outputs: John Williams
```

This will search for a capital letter followed by any number of lower-case letters, then a space, then a repeat of the previous pattern.

Outside of this, you could consider using Named Entity Recognition (NER) using pre-built libraries to identify names in text. Please see here for more details. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/nlp-application-named-entity-recognition-ner-in-python-with-spacy/

Edit:

I should add that in the event where there are multiple names within the same sentence, you can apply `re.findall()`:

```
sentence = 'I am going out with John Williams and William Smith today'
names = re.findall(r"[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+ [A-Z]{1}[a-z]+", sentence)
print(names) # Outputs: ['John Williams', 'William Smith']
```